# How to read invalid SSL certificates details using Java code?

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I like to read invalid cerificate details using java code. Say for giving website. https://self-signed.badssl.com/

I tried below code

```
package com.company;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        certInformation("https://self-signed.badssl.com/");
    }

    public static void certInformation(String aURL) throws Exception{
        URL destinationURL = new URL(aURL);
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) destinationURL.openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        Certificate[] certs = conn.getServerCertificates();
        for (Certificate cert : certs) {
            System.out.println("Certificate is: " + cert);
            if(cert instanceof X509Certificate) {
                X509Certificate x = (X509Certificate ) cert;
                System.out.println(x.getIssuerDN());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which works for "www.google.com" but not working for "https://self-signed.badssl.com/" Site.
I am getting below error

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:316)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:310)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1639)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:162)
    at com.company.Main.certInformation(Main.java:18)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1621)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
    ... 18 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Could anyone know reason and guide me ?

Comment: If you just want to grab the certificates you don't need to use `HttpsURLConnection`. Create an SSLContext with a custom trustmanager and hostnameverifier that just accepts everything. You will receive the peer certificates in your TrustManager function.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk nit: SSLContext doesn't have any hostnameverifier; that's at HttpsURLConnection level only, and now deprecated in favor of 'endpoint identification' in JSSE -- in the _default_ trustmanager. **Also:** a nonprogramming solution is `keytool -printcert -sslserver $host[:$post]` which already does what you want. But only for badssl server-cert cases; for protocol and cipher errors you can't get the cert(s) by any means, Java or other.